# Error when writing data to postgresql using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, csv

I am trying to save csv column value in postgres database. i used panda to fetch csv column value. but whenever i tried to save the column value in my database table column, i getting a error.
here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

file = request.files['csvFile[]']
print('file.filename: ',file.filename)
jh = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={"name": str})
names = jh.name
print(names)

user = GenderInfo(name=jh.name)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

this is the result after print

> names=jh.name

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOjj8.png)

and i am getting the error frequently

> 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

i searched google for this problem, but i can't solve this.Any help regarding this would be appreciated or if there is any other alternative way for saving csv column data in database column.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback, I think this has more to do with how the `GenderInfo` Constructor parses the `jh.name` Series.

Comment: see the  edited question, i add an image. "jh.name"  print all the gender name in csv file

Comment: Thanks for updating the post. What I was actually looking for though is the full python traceback that is printed to the console. It should look something like this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/repo/global/panda_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(hash(df.name))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1045, in __hash__
    ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: I edited my post again. see the newly attached image

Comment: Oh I see, the `try except` block is suppressing the full traceback. Can you add a `raise` statement at the end of the `except` block and post the traceback text in the question?

Comment: plz see the edited question sir

Comment: In order to really answer this I also need to know how the `db.session` is created (what database you're using) and how the `GenderInfo` class is defined. I suspect that the `GenderInfo` class constructor expects a single name for the `name` parameter, but you are passing it a whole list (actually a `pandas.Series` object).

Comment: I used postgres database here. and genderInfo table contains only one column named name. So now how to insert a single value from csv to db?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the module you're using for postres the api that it exposes (`db.session.add`) seems odd to me. The simplest solution would be to iterate through the `jh.name` series and insert each one using the `GenderInfo` Constructor. However there may be a more efficient way. What module are you using for the database connection and how is the `GenderInfo` class (function?) defined?

Comment: I used marshmallow to save the objects in table instant of writing row sql query

Answer (score 0):

it's done!
here is the code

```
def upload_cs():
    file = request.files['excelFile[]']
    stream = io.StringIO(file.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(stream)

    # Validate and deserialize input
    data, errors = genderInfoDto.load(file)

    print('data: ', data)


    for row in csv_input:
        jh = GenderInfo.query.filter_by(name=row['name']).first()
        print('GenderInfo: ', jh)
        if jh:
            return Response(json.dumps({'status': 'failed', 'message': 'gender already exists.'}), status=200,
                            mimetype='application/json')
        print(row['name'])
        user = GenderInfo(row['name'])
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    result = genderInfoDto.dump(user).data
    stream.seek(0)

    return Response(json.dumps({'status': 'success', 'message': 'file upload successfully  .', 'data': result}),
                    status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```